# Risk in having the PAC file in a server with no authorisation

Tags: proxy, http-proxy

So basically I’ve put my PAC-file under a non-secure web server with no authentication whatsoever in my organization. Later, I found out that there have been many attacks using this file type in other countries.

How true is it that there’s a risk here? Any worker could have downloaded the PAC file from their browser and see it as it doesn’t require authorization and the server hasn’t been secured with TLS or something similar.

Should I secure the server (https)? I don’t know if browsers can read the PAC file from a secure server. I’m a little lost, but I need to understand if this is a risk.

Comment: What do you mean by "attacks in other countries using this file"? How does TLS prevent your employees from downloading a PAC file (has nothing to do with Authorization in particular)? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I mean there have been attacks in financial institutions in Brazil by exploiting PAC files, some of those briefly explained in this article: https://securelist.com/pac-the-problem-auto-config/57891/ .... Regarding TLS, it was just an idea. I've also read that I could simply use a GPO in Windows with Active Directory in order to manage Access to the PAC-file. I just need to forbid users from seeing/downloading the PAC files to avoid any risk.

Comment: No, the users **need** access to the PAC files. That is how they work; the browser downloads them. The attacks did not happen because users accessed the files, but because an attacker was able to modify them! Read the 2. section in the link you're using.

Comment: @vidarlo Ok, I got that. I just need to make sure an attacker won't modify my PAC. So how do I do that? I'm thinking GPO is all I need, but I wanna be sure. In the meantime, I keep learning about this.

Comment: GPO can somwhat enforce it - but note that many group policies are only applied at login and at regular intervals - and a process running as administrator can often overwrite them. When it comes to securing against modification, you should restrict access to the webserver hosting them, and the DHCP or AD servers handing out configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the important thing to guard against is anyone *modifying* which PAC file the end users reference, not preventing users from *reading* the PAC file itself - which you won't be able to do anyway, as it must be readable by all your endpoint systems, and therefore by all your users, to work.

Put another way, what the article tells me is that the threat is twofold:

1. malware can alter what file the endpoint uses for its proxy
   configuration, and
2. malicious actors can alter what the unsecured autoproxy server serves as the officially blessed PAC file.

I'm not a Windows administrator anymore, but as I recall from the days when I worked with them more directly, I believe you can control which PAC files your users are using through the application of Group Policy. If not, some other form of File Integrity Monitoring may be useful. As the article you cite mentions, it's very difficult to distinguish a good PAC file from a malicious one just by reading the file, but it's much easier to detect when something changed without it being authorized.

So both attacks should be addressed by Group Policy or FIM in conjunction with antimalware on the endpoint and on the PAC web server. If possible, protecting the download of the PAC file with TLS will also help. But for the file to do its job, it has to be readable by all comers.

Comment: I see what you mean. So basically what I need to do is configure the Microsoft Group Policy Object to prevent my users from ever modifying the PAC file. As long as I do that, it doesn't matter if they can see or download the script. Did I understand this correctly? Please respond so I can upvote your answer :)

Comment: You **need** to understand the threat. You obviously have no idea about how this works **or** the attack in Brazil that you refer to.

Comment: I've read the article, and what it tells me is that the threat is twofold: 1. malware can alter what file the endpoint uses for its proxy configuration, and 2. malicious actors can alter what the unsecured autoproxy server serves as the officially blessed PAC file. Both of these should be addressed by Group Policy or FIM in conjunction with antimalware on the endpoint and on the PAC web server. If possible, protecting the download of the PAC file with TLS will also help. But for the file to do its job, it has to be readable by all comers, and that's what I'm advising the OP against blocking.

Comment: @MikeMcManus My comment was not directed at you - sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: No problem. It gave me an opportunity to clarify the answer.